# Anyway to print document from iPad App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have calculator app i want that result user can print.I have searched a lot on forums some say you can some not.Any related library which can sort this issue

Answer (score 0):

Printing is possible. Take a look at the [Apple page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW1) on it. This should get you going in the right direction!

Here is a tutorial: [Deleting and printing files](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi3DDRFLaF4).

And you should take a close look at the [printing workflow part](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW14).

Comment: is there any related tutorial for printing tutorial